# I need to move a list heading from left to right

Tags: css

My page is www.c5d.co.uk/barfour.php

On the top left hand side, is an unordered list which is styled to be horizontal.

It's the change of address, contact us and directions bit

I thought that  by using float left it would move to the right hand side which is where I want it. I think it looks better on the right.

Can anyone have a quick look and tell me where I have gone wrong please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the `float:left` off of your `#pagemenucontainer`. Then, you can `float:right` your `#pagemenu`. Lastly, delete your `#header's` first `<br>` element to fix the spacing.

Comment: BTW, you should avoid using `<br>` tags for spacing. You can use margins or padding instead. Or, sometimes `position:relative` and `left:10px` or `top:-10px` e.g. will do the trick.

Comment: Do you mean in passages of text ? Or with other items ? I'm Ok with the HTML but CSS is fairly new to me.

Three months ago all this was still in frames !

So I feel I've learned a  lot quickly, but there's loads more I coud do I'm sure.  There's probably stuff in the Style  sheet that does nothing but as I moved two sheets into one and it all works OK, I try to mess slowly and see how each adjustment reacts

Can't answer again today. Work calls, 

Antony

Comment: Antony if sfjedi's answer solved your problem please give him the checkmark so that he can earn the credit and so that the rest of us don't answer an already answered question

Answer (score 0):

I added: **style="width:100%;** to the div "pagemenucontainer" and **style="float:right";** to the UL "pagemenu", that did it for me:

```
<div id="pagemenucontainer" style="width:100%;">
<ul id="pagemenu" class="menu" style="float:right">
<li><a href="http://www.c5d.co.uk/addresschangefour.php">Change of Address</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.c5d.co.uk/contactagcfour.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.c5d.co.uk/directionstoclubfour.php">Directions</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response the answer from sfjedui was easier for me though.  I do appreciate the idea.

Antony

Comment: As long as you got it working! This is a community, it makes no difference who helps, as long as there is help. Have a great day Antony!